# Python - While loop goes into infinite loop. What am i doing wrong?

Tags: python

I wrote my code and someone told me to do while loop like this, but it's not right. It goes in to a infinite loop and as a newbiee I'm not sure what's wrong. I have looked at other searches and don't understand how they fixed their code because it is all different. Don't mark this as a duplicate because it stops me from getting answers directly for my code. I'm a newbie and I'll take all of your crap. Thanks

```
print ("enter a number 1 - 2: ")
userin = input()

while userin != 1 or userin != 2:
    print ("Enter a number that is 1 or 2")

    if userin == "1":
        print ("\n One")
    elif userin == "2":
        print ("\n One", "\n Two")
    else:
        print ("Enter a number that is 1 or 2")
```

This was the original code without the while loop:

```
print ("Enter a number (2 - 3): ")
userin = input()


if userin == "2": 
    print("\n One","\n Two") 
elif userin == "3":
    print("\n One", "\n Two", "\Three")
else: print("Invalid. Enter a number2 -3!")
```

Comment: `while userin != 1 or userin != 2` should be `while userin != "1" or userin != "2":`

Comment: Haha ... Python code that is not correctly indented is broken, not just "bad style".

Comment: It is important to show your indentation with python because it completely changes the meaning.    However, the clue is that `input()` returns a text string (`str`) in Python 3, `1` is an integer (`int`), whereas `"1"` is also a text string.

Comment: Don't change your post that dramatically after you already got answers.  Your edit invalidated all answers and in fact made the question completely useless.  If you think someone's suggestion of a duplicate is wrong, say why you think so; but don't edit out the whole question.

Answer (score 3):

The test `userin != "1" or userin != "2"` is always true.  If the user enters a 1, then the second part is true.  If the user enters a 2, then the first part is true.  So, the loop never ends.  Try using `and` instead of `or`.

Comment: i tried using and but still get the infinite loop. maybe the way i used the whole while loop is wrong. because my goal is when the number 1 is input i get one displayed or when 2 is input i get one two displayed on separate lines.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your code is that you just take the user input once at the very beginning and the while loop continues to run based on that input resulting in an infinite loop. Basically, you never take the input again

Try using the following code:

```
print ("enter a number 1 - 2: ")
userin = input()

while userin != "1" and userin != "2":
    print ("Enter a number that is 1 or 2")
    userin = input()

if userin == "1":
    print ("One\n")
elif userin == "2":
    print ("Two\n")
```

**Explanation:** Initially you take an input from the user. And the while loop is started with a check for whether the input is neither 1 nor 2 i.e the loop only proceeds if userin is neither 1 nor 2. Further if it is neither 1 nor 2, the user is asked to re-enter a number. And input is taken again using `userin = input()`
Once the user enters either of 1 or 2, the loop exits and "One" or "Two" is printed according to the user's final input.

Comment: You're still comparing strings with integers.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Please try this...
ip_list = [1, 2]  # input list
print ("enter a number 1 - 2: ")
userin = input()

while userin not in ip_list:
    print ("Enter a number that is 1 or 2")
    userin = input()


>>> while userin not in ip_list:
...     print("Enter a number that is 1 - 2!")
...     userin = input()
...
Enter a number that is 1 - 2! 
5
Enter a number that is 1 - 2!
6
Enter a number that is 1 - 2!
-1
Enter a number that is 1 - 2!
0
Enter a number that is 1 - 2!
9
Enter a number that is 1 - 2!
1 <===== Here it exits while loop
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple problems.  For one thing, when is `userin` both equal to `1` *and* equal to `2`?  Never!  You need to use `userin != 1 and userin != 2`.  That isn't quite right either, though, because you are comparing strings with integers. You see `input()` returns a string, but you are comparing it to `1` and `2`.  You should be using `userin != '1'
 and userin != '2'` so that you are comparing strings to strings.  Your final problem is that you keep comparing `userin` to `1` and `2`, but you never redefine it after the original time.  You need to add an `input()` call into your `while` loop.  Your final code:

```
print ("enter a number 1 - 2: ")
userin = input()

while userin != '1' and userin != '2':
    print ("Enter a number that is 1 or 2")
    userin = input()
    if userin == "1":
        print ("\n One")
    elif userin == "2":
        print ("\n One", "\n Two")
```

Your `else` is redundant because if `userin` is neither `1` nor `2`, the `while` loop will run again and print it.